# Proof that $E(F_X(X/\sigma))=\frac12$ for every positive $\sigma$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Define $X$ to be continuous random variable **symmetric about zero** with cdf $F_X$ and let $\sigma > 0$ denote a constant. Now show the following:
$$ E\left[F_X\left(\frac{X}{\sigma}\right)\right] = 0.5$$
How can one prove this claim? Since the cdf $F_X$ isn't necessarily linear, we can't place the expectation into the cdf, which would render the problem trivial. Additionally, I've concluded that the cdf is convex from $-\infty$ to $0$ and concave from $0$ to $\infty$ as it is symmetric about zero. This means we can't use Jensen's inequality either. What am I missing?

Comment: Since $F_X(x)=P(Y<x)$ for every $x$,where $Y$ can be any random variable distributed like $X$, choose such a random variable $Y$ independent of $X$ and note that one wants to show that $p=\frac12$ with $p=P(Y<X/\sigma)$. Now, $(-X,-Y)$ is distributed like $(X,Y)$ hence $p=P(-Y<-X/\sigma)=P(Y>X/\sigma)=1-p$, QED.

Comment: Nice! Thank you so much :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ be the PDF of $X$, which should be symmetric about the origin; i.e. $f(-x)=f(x)$. Then, the CDF is
$$
F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{1}
$$
The symmetry of $f$ means that
$$
\begin{align}
F(-x)
&=\int_{-\infty}^{-x}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_x^\infty f(-t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_x^\infty f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t-\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\[4pt]
&=1-F(x)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
The expected value is
$$
\begin{align}
E(F(X/\sigma))
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)F(x/\sigma)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(-x)F(-x/\sigma)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{4}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)(1-F(x/\sigma))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{5}\\
&=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{6}\\
&=\frac12\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(3)$: formula for expected value
$(4)$: substitute $x\mapsto-x$
$(5)$: symmetry of $f$ and $(2)$
$(6)$: average $(3)$ and $(5)$
$(7)$: $f$ is a PDF

Comment: Choosing $\phi$ to denote the PDF is unfortunate since usual choices for the CDF, PDF and characteristic function are $F$, $f$ and... $\phi$, respectively.

Comment: @Did: is that better? Sorry, but I don't remember which books I used in undergrad, but I seem to remember them using $\Phi$ and $\phi$ as CDF and PDF. I see that on Wikipedia and in several of your comments, it is $F$ and $f$. I have changed the notation in my answer (though I did state that $\phi$ was the PDF, so this is just a notational issue).

Comment: @robjohn Thank you so much for the additional proof. It's always nice to see a problem solved from multiple angles. Really appreciate your effort. Regarding notation: I've often seen people use $\Phi$ and $\phi$ to denote the cdf and pdf of a standard normal, so that might be why you remember this convention.